# What should be inside the model.fit() function for training images in Unsupervised Learning using Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, theano, unsupervised-learning

I have created the model but I'm confused about the second parameter,i.e. the 'labels' parameter. What should be put in that place?

Comment: Could you post your code as well?

Comment: If you are confused about what a label is, maybe it is best that you study a bit of theory before trying to implement anything

Comment: I know what a label is, but we are talking about unsupervised learning over here.

Comment: If you want to do unsupervised than you need to specify what model you want to use, and where your network comes into play.